# UDP client stucks in recvfrom only in specific situation

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a C++ code that implements an UDP server and client.

The code works fine when I write two codes, one for the server and another for the client, as in this example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/ .

What I'm trying to do is to write a client function and a server function in the same code. The ideia is that I select how the program is going to work with the command lines argument.

The problem is that, implementing this way and testing in two terminals running the same code, with different command line arguments, one for server and another for client, the client stucks in the recvfrom, when receiving the server response.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define PORT 32000

int send(){
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
    
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 
    
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    
    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    
    socklen_t len;
    int n; 
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
            len); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

    return 0; 
}

int receive(){
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    struct sockaddr_in   servaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    
    int n;
    socklen_t len; 
    
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr)); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 
        
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer); 

    return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int command = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(command == 0){
        send();
        
    }
    if(command == 1){
        receive();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The expected results is something like this, that i get when running the client and the server on separated codes:

Server side:

> Hello from client
>
> Hello message sent

Client side:

> Hello message sent
>
> Hello from server

But what I get when running the code above is

Server side:

> Hello from client
>
> Hello message sent

Client side:

> Hello message sent
>
> ---gets stucked here---

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `send()` function, you are not initializing `len` to the length of the buffer where `recvfrom` can store the client address.

According to the man page for `recvfrom`:

> ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
>                          struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
>
> If src_addr is not NULL,  and  the  underlying  protocol  provides  the
>   source  address  of  the  message, that source address is placed in the
>   buffer pointed to by src_addr.  In this case, addrlen is a value-result
>   argument.  Before the call, it should be initialized to the size of the
>   buffer associated with src_addr.  Upon return, addrlen  is  updated  to
>   contain the actual size of the source address.

It's not working because the client address isn't being properly received so the response message is being sent to the wrong address. To resolve your problem, you just need to initialize `len` before the call to `recvfrom`:

```
socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr); // The size of the buffer you're passing to store the client address
```

Comment: Just one question: in my client i shouldn't do this initialization?

Comment: Ah yes, you should also do this in your `receive()` function.  It wasn't causing your test program to fail but it might cause other issues.

Leaving len unitialized could result in memory corruption if it happens to end up with a value greater than `sizeof(serveaddr)`